# Django + Stripe , how to add address field in Stripe checkout page ,

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I have integrated Django with Stripe. After I submit the card details in the frontend , it gives below error

```
InvalidRequestError at /api/ChargeView/
As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports
```

1. How can I ask the customers to fill the address in the checkout page ?
2. If the customers billing address exists, how can I pass it to checkout page ?

VIEWS.PY

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'backend/index1.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['key'] = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        
        return context


class ChargeView(TemplateView):

    def post(self, request):
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=100,
            currency='GBP',
            
            description='Hat purchase.',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
        return HttpResponse('<p>Thank you for your payment!</p>')
```

CHECK OUT PAGE

```
<form action="{% url 'payments-charge' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
        class="stripe-button"
        data-key="{{ key }}"
        data-description="You are purchasing: Hat from this site."
        data-amount="100" 
        data-currency="gbp"
        data-locale="auto"
      ></script>
    </form>
```

The possible error location is the ChargeView section. I have installed the Stripe app with Django and configured the test keys.

Comment: Try passing `data-billing-address=true` to collect the users's address : https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout#highly-recommended

Comment: Maybe this can be useful for adding the billing address to the checkout page: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/customization#billing-address-collection

The billing address is not a Charge attribute, but a Card one. The card can be added to the Charge as its `source` parameter. I don't know exactly how to create a charge with billing address in one go, but this might give you a hint to unblock yourself.

Comment: Thanks you all, @karllekko it works with the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you're using is a legacy version of Checkout that has been deprecated well over a year ago. Stripe since then built a brand new version of Checkout which is documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

That version handles a lot more features beyond simply collecting the card details, such as supporting multiple line items, 3D Secure authentication, new payment methods such as iDEAL with more coming.

You should make sure that you move to that newer version and drop Legacy Checkout as you're building a new integration.